How to change the numeration of sections from "0.x" to "1", "2", etc.?
So I've looked through some similar (but not the same) questions, I've look through the template I was given but I don't understand how do I change the numeration of the sections from "0.x" to simple "1", "2", etc.? I don't need any subsections so I don't need these "0.x".
Here's the preamble:
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 
\setlength{\headheight}{14.49998pt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage{tempora}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 top=20mm,
 }
 \usepackage{amssymb}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{euscript}  
\geometry{a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2.5cm,right=1cm}
\linespread{1.0}
\sloppy
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000
\relpenalty=\maxdimen  
\binoppenalty=\maxdimen

\begin{document}
\section{Вступ}
some text here for the example
\end{document}



That is the default behavior when using the report class (as you are using). In the report class, chapters are expected before sections. Therefore, in your document, consider including a chapter before starting with a section, or switch to the article class. Edit: I saw that you have edited your question, so let me ask you: what class are you using within that document?

For code format, ``` must appear on its own line.

@JoséAreia thank you and initially I've been using the report class since I saw that in the given template...

@stephan Please refer to my answer for additional insight into your question.

if you use report then your top level section should be \chapter not \section, or use article

@JoséAreia already seen your answer, now I get it

Excellent! I'm glad I could help.

As I mentioned in my comment, I think you should evaluate the use of the correct class for your document. The report class is designed to start with a chapter rather than a section. Therefore, you should consider using the article class or a similar class.
However, if you are determined to proceed with the report class, you can easily modify the numbering with the following code.
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {\thesection.}
  {1em}
  {}

% Change section numbering to single-level.
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}
This is the first section.

\section{Other Section Title}
This is the second section.

\end{document}

It results in the following:

Once again, I do not think this is a suitable solution to use, as it goes against the class definitions. However, if it is your choice to proceed this way, feel free to do so.
I hope you understand, and I hope this was helpful to you.

I see no reason to use report if you don't want chapters.
Use article. Meanwhile, also fix your code.

You don't want to load packages multiple times
Your math will be in Computer Modern, which clashes with a Times-like font such as Tempora
Setting geometry parameters twice is just confusing yourself
Setting \parindent to zero is confusing readers
Setting \sloppy calls for badly formatted paragraphs
\widowpenalty, \clubpenalty, \relpenalty and \binoppenalty should never be set to 10000 (and \maxdimen is the wrong parameter anyway)

I suggest to load newtxmath, which also supersedes amssymb.
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % no longer required
\usepackage[english,ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{euscript}  

\usepackage{tempora}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% to use Euler Script
\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathcal{U}{eus}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet\mathcal{bold}{U}{eus}{b}{n}

%\linespread{1.0} % it's the default

\geometry{
  a4paper,
  top=2cm,
  bottom=2cm,
  left=2.5cm,
  right=1cm,
  headheight=14.5pt,
}

% The following should not be done
%\sloppy
%\clubpenalty=10000
%\widowpenalty=10000
%\relpenalty=\maxdimen  
%\binoppenalty=\maxdimen

\begin{document}

\section{Вступ}

some text here for the example

some math $a+\mathcal{X}$

\end{document}


Unfortunately, euscript doesn't work in connection with newtxmath, but the workaround is simple.
